# Chrome Extension - need to add chrome.browser actions in content scripts

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So basically I need to do a couple of things

1. chrome.webrequests.onBeforeRequest.addlisteners
2. chrome.browser.addbadgetext
3. chrome.tabs.query

in a content script. The reason why I want this in content script is because I want the above to trigger without clicking the extension icon on the active page. How can I do that?

Below is my manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "My Ext",
"description": "My Ext desc",
"icons": { 
    "16":"logo-sm.png", 
    "48":"logo-sm.png", 
    "128":"logo-sm.png" 
},
"version": "1.0",
"homepage_url": "abc.com",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "favicon.png",
    "default_title": "My ext"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
"web_accessible_resources": ["oxy-logo-sm.png"],
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "js":["scripts/content.js"],
   "run_at": "document_start"   
}],
"permissions": ["activeTab", "webRequest", "tabs", "<all_urls>"]
```

}

Comment: You can't do that. These functions are not available in content scripts. Use a background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks for the quick reply... I already tried that but no dice. Let me share my manifest,json's part

...
"background":{
 "scripts":["scripts/background.js"],
 "persistent":true
}

and in background.js
I have alert("aaaa");

and it doesn't shows up

Comment: I figured out that the alert comes just once, when you refresh the extension itself on the extensions page. Not when you open a new tab and open a web page. I need this to be working on all the pages.

Comment: anyone out there???

Comment: Use `chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function callback)` in your background script and do whatever you want to do in the newly created tab.

Comment: @elegant-user - thanks a ton!!!!! it worked. Just a last favor. Some data needs to be passed from the background script to the popup.html. Please note that the script in background.js gets executed prior opening the popup. I tried
`chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
msg: "something_completed", 
data: {
subject: "Loading",
content: "Just completed!"
}
});`
and in popup.js, I have
`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("background.js got a message")
    }
);` and I don't see the message

Comment: Use `localstorage.set` in BG and `localstorage.get` in popup instead of messaging.

Comment: @elegant-user - thanks! that worked. You are my hero today!!!!

Comment: @AmritPalSingh, All the best!